# I added a new table in SSMS, and added a new DBSet to my DBContext instance, but am getting an invalid object error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a database connected to my .Net Core project and added a new table to the database. I added the corresponding model with the class/entities in the project and added a new `DBSet` to my `DBContext` Instance, but when I try to query the new table in my program, I get the following error: `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'SalesOrdersNonLegacies'.'`

In SSMS, the new table is called `dbo.SalesOrdersNonLegacy` (all of the tables are in the dbo schema, but the dbo isn't included in the DBSet declaration) and I added the DBSet as follows:

```
public DbSet<SalesOrdersNonLegacy> SalesOrdersNonLegacies { get; set; }
```

I added a model `SalesOrdersNonLegacy.cs` with the respective entities. Am I missing something obvious? I rebuilt the project containing the model and DBContext. Is it a permission error just adding a new table willie nillie?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess you aren't connected to the same database in your different applications.

Comment: It's all one application, and the DBContext is reading from a connection string referencing the one database being used. Is there something to where I need to update the database in Visual Studio? Like some sort of caching issue? I can post the context file if that will help.

Comment: You've missed my point. I'm suggesting that the database you connected to in SSMS and the database you are connecting to from your application you are making are not the same. Perhaps, for example, you created the table `dbo.SalesOrdersNonLegacy` in `master` in error.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. The database referenced in the connection string of my program is the same as the one I'm connected to in SSMS. I'm querying multiple other tables in the program from the same database without issue. It's just this new table that I added that is throwing an error, so I'm not sure if adding a model and DBSet was enough to update Visual Studio's reference to the database. edit: The new table is in the same database, not master or any other.

Comment: [Your property name doesn't match your table name, which is the default convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#table-name)

Comment: The connection string is as follows: "Data Source=serverName\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB_NAME; Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" I don't know if it doesn't include any of what you mentioned it uses a default?

Comment: I think you're link about the table name convention is what did it. I will update as soon as I correct that.

Comment: @Crowcoder That was it! Sadly, I had it backwards with respect to the name of the DBSet and the actual table name being used. If you want to set that as the answer, I can accept it. Thank y'all for your help!

Comment: Seems like a pluralization problem? You say you've called the table ...Legacy and the C# side ...Legacy also but EF is forming queries as if the table is called ...Legacies. Are your tables normally plural and you're getting EF to convert from plural/singular?

Comment: @CaiusJard Exactly, except in my case I had written them backwards, so the table name wasn't properly written in the correct spot.

Comment: Are you sure that you can query the table under this connection? I mean if you go to ssms with this user name and password that you have in connection string, will you be able to query select * from SalesOrdersNonLegacy
maybe you need to do something like Grant select on SalesOrdersNonLegacy to Role

Comment: Yes, I can query the table SalesOrdersNonLegacy. The problem was that the DBSet model and name were swapped in the code I wrote, which explains why my program was saying it didn't exist; I didn't name the table as it's named in SSMS. @Crowcoder had the right link that pointed me in the right direction which was just me not naming my model class correctly.
Edit - we can close this question or take crowcoder's message as solution as it was just a misspelling on my part.